# How to use custom colors for icons in gmap v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am in the process of upgrading my gmap v2 to v3. My code previously used GIcon to create Icons array and based upon the heat map values. I am unable to update the code and don't know how to change the code here. My piece of code is:

```
var icons = []
for (var i=1; i<6; i++) {
    var icon = new GIcon();
    icon.image = "/images/gmap/clusters/" + i + "s.png";
    icon.smallImage = "/images/gmap/clusters/" + i + "s.png";
    icon.shadow = "/images/gmap/small_shadow.png";
    icon.iconSize =  new google.maps.iconSize(16,27); //small
    icon.shadowSize = new  google.maps.shadowSize(37, 35);
    icon.iconAnchor = new google.maps.iconAnchor(13, 20);
    icon.infoWindowAnchor = new google.maps.infoWindowAnchor(12, 0);
    icons.push(icon);
}
```

And this gets called by the statement

```
var m = addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(geo[1], geo[0]), icons[heat - 1]);
```

Please suggest how to get rid of this GIcon() and use it so that I can have different icons based upon the conditional value.

Comment: The v3 API supports [custom marker icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons), they are defined (slightly) differently from the way they were in the v2 API, but the translation is straightforward.  What problem are you having? What does your v3 code look like? [google.maps.Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon)

Comment: Well, I use a js to call another js which has the gmap functionality. The V3 code is too big to attach here, can you provide your email address so that I can send you there.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create your own colored marker :

```
var pinAlreadySeen = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|8E7569",
    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
```

Look at `chst` paramter in URL

`chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|8E7569"`

After the `|`, you can write your own RGB code, which correspond to the desired color. Just replace my `8E7569` by the HEX code you want